# When to release NSUrlConnection object

Tags: iphone

What is the correct point at which to release a NSUrlConnection object?

In my program, I alloc a NSUrlConnection, and then initWithRequest to kick off asynchronously.

I am now responsible for releasing the object - when do I/can I release? Immediately if I'm not using it again?

Comment: I checked retaincount after creating my NSUrlConnection - it was 2.

I feel that it is correct to release immediately.  Anybody want to contradict this, or create an answer that says this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your usage of the NSUrlConnection can be released immediately.

The framework will release when it has finished with it.

Comment: I think its not a good idea. I checked with my code, and then it is having a crash. And apple sample code did not release it either. They release it in the delegate call e.g. didFinishLoading ...

Answer (score 10):

When you are done with the `NSURLConnection`.  You'll know you're done with it when your `NSURLConnection` delegate receives `- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` or `- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`.  Just release it at the end of those two methods.

Comment: This causes my application to crash with BAD_ACCESS. I believe you can release it straight away as @Alan says.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to release it until the framework issues you a notification that it's done, in, say, `connection:didFailWithError:`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late (your question was posted in 2009, over a year ago) but I was having the some trouble with my NSUrlConnection code. NSUrlConnection kept crashing and I thought the crash was related to my release of NSUrlConnection `[theConnection release];`. I was writing my code as in Apple's example [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html), but I ended up releasing the connection after it was created in "Listing 1" rather than releasing it where Apple does in both `didFailWithError` and `connectionDidFinishLoading` and it seems to work fine. I'm not completely sure, but maybe both of those delegates were being called and a double release was what was causing the crash. I wasn't sure I could release my NSUrlConnection object right after it was created until I read this question but that seemed to do the trick.